# Why is the American version of the manga split into three parts?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I'm trying to read the Yu-Gi-Oh! manga at the moment and I realized, that it was seemingly split into three (?) parts:

1. Yu-Gi-Oh!
2. Yu-Gi-Oh! Duelist
3. Yu-Gi-Oh! ???

What is the third part of the manga? Why was it split up in such a fashion? I can imagine that they wanted to separate out all the "Duel Cards" parts, because that's what the kids were most likely interested in, but still? Why leave out the last 100 (or so) chapters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are referring to *Yu-Gi-Oh! Millennium World* then according to Wikipedia

> Viz released the first volume of the Yu-Gi-Oh! manga up to the end of the Monster World arc under its original title. Starting from the last chapter of the seventh Japanese volume, the Duelist Kingdom, Dungeon Dice Monsters, and Battle City arcs are released under the title Yu-Gi-Oh!: Duelist, while the Memory World arc was released as Yu-Gi-Oh! Millennium World.

Source: [Yu-Gi-Oh! - Manga (Second Paragraph)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!#Manga)

What this means is that the Viz Media release using the original name *Yu-Gi-Oh!* finishes at **Millenium Enemy 10: The Last Die Roll** which is Chapter 59 of Volume 7 of the Manga in Japan (according to the chapter list [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Yu-Gi-Oh!_chapters)). *Yu-Gi-Oh!: Duelist* starts from the next chapter and continues to the end of **Volume 31** and *Yu-Gi-Oh! Millennium World* is the final Arc which starts at Volume 32 and finishes the at the end

As for why? it seems to be a decision by Viz Media. while i don't know for sure i would suspect that it was because in the beginning there was several games portrayed in the manga with *Magic & Wizards* only appearing a couple of times in the first seven volumes. at the start of the Duelist Kingdom Arc *Magic & Wizards* returned and became the main game that the series focused on (with the exception of *Dungeon Dice Monsters*). the Memory World Arc however focused on a Table Top RPG (the precursor to *Magic & Wizards*)

So the first Viz Media release *Yu-Gi-Oh!* featured multiple games. after that *Yu-Gi-Oh!: Duelist* focused mainly on Magic & Wizards while *Yu-Gi-Oh! Millennium World* focused on a entire different game

Viz Media however has also been re-releasing the series as a [3-in-1 edition](https://www.viz.com/read/manga/yu-gi-oh-3-in-1-edition/all) as the currently listed volumes of it (as of 23/08/2017) have covers from [*Yu-Gi-Oh!*, *Yu-Gi-Oh!: Duelist* and *Yu-Gi-Oh! Millennium World*](https://www.viz.com/read/yu-gi-oh/section/25695/more)