# Are the Japanese and US releases of the Yu-Gi-Oh! manga the same?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Is the Japanese manga version of Yu-Gi-Oh same as the US manga version? Also, if it is not, what is the difference?

Comment: [This discussion of how the manga is divided](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/41974/2604) is probably relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The editor of the English Version of the Manga, *Jason Thompson* stated that the licensing of the *Yu-Gi-Oh! manga* had not been entirely coordinated, so Viz decided to use many of the original character names and to "keep it more or less violent and gory." Thompson said that the manga "was almost unchanged from the Japanese original." Because the core fanbase of the series was, according to Thompson, "8-year-old boys (and a few incredible fangirls)," and because the series had little interest from "hardcore, Japanese-speaking fans, the kind who run scanlation sites and post on message boards" as the series was perceived to be "too mainstream," the Viz editors allowed Thompson "a surprising amount of leeway with the translation." Thompson said he hoped that he did not "abuse" the leeway he was given. In a 2004 interview, the editors of the United States Shonen Jump mentioned that Americans were surprised when reading the stories in Volumes 1 through 7, as they had not appeared on television as a part of the Yu-Gi-Oh! Duel Monsters anime. Takahashi added "The story is quite violent, isn't it? [laughs]"

## Source